# How to generate Key and typeof(key) pairs in C#

Tags: c#, xml

This is a strange XML File, I had come across which possess dictonary with set of key and typof key pairs with values inside of it.  Can any one enlighten how to generate this using C#.

```
<dict>
    <key>175</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Track ID</key><integer>175</integer>
        <key>Name</key><string>Kattikida</string>
        <key>Artist</key><string>Anthony Dasan, Manasi, Anitha</string>
        <key>Album Artist</key><string>Anirudh Ravichander</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Some effort will be appreciated. What is the output expected?

Comment: If you use an `array<System.ValueType>` instead of making a `struct` can be useful.

Comment: Better title: create a xml file with a key/value dictionary

Comment: @PatrickHofman The code provides is the output required, constructing XML using c#

Comment: Can you expand on exactly what this xml is?  It looks like it might be a set of music sound track information where each track has an id that is being used as a key.  In that case you should start by modeling the data with classes then write serialization and deserialization code.  Once you attempt that you can post any questions about issues you come across.

Comment: Looks like a badly designed xml structure. Second <dict> is more a class with four _equally named_ properties... I'd change the xml structure before proceeding

Comment: No wonder it's a badly designed  XML format, it's iTunes export format. Thanks in for the reply guys.

Answer (score -2):

You would have to write your own XML Serializer probably using XML document, you would then have full control over what you generate and could easily use `GetType().Name` to use the type as the name of the attribute

however anything trying to read such a file would need to be just as custom

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx